# redeclaring interfaces in multiple jar files

Tags: java, interface

I have several interfaces (e.g. `mypackage.IMyInterface`) which are implemented in multiple software modules. On the other hand, I use a build script that puts these modules in seperate jar files (for versioning reasons).

**Would it be "ok" to include the same interface in each individual jar file.**

Just to make myself perfectly clear. The package `mypackage` would be included in all jar files, and they would all have a copy of the exact same `mypackage\IMyInterface.class` file.

I've seen this practice in some open-source jar files. But I'm not sure if it's good practice or if it happens by accident.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bad practice.

A package shouldn't be shared between different jars.

At least an interface (or a class) should not be copied in multiple jars.

The best is to extract common interfaces (and classes) and put them in a separate jar and import that jar everywhere it is used.

So going from this situation:

*mylibfirst.jar* (jar1):

- `com.mygroup.mylib.MyCommonInterface`
- `com.mygroup.mylib.MyClass1`

*mylibsecond.jar* (Jar2):

- `com.mygroup.mylib.MyCommonInterface`
- `com.mygroup.mylib.MyClass2`

To the following:

*mylibfirst.jar* (Jar1, using *mylib.jar*):

- `com.mygroup.mylib.first.MyClass1`

*mylibsecond.jar* (Jar2, using *mylib.jar*):

- `com.mygroup.mylib.second.MyClass2`

*mylib.jar* (Jar3):

- `com.mygroup.mylib.MyCommonInterface`

Comment: maybe calling jar3 "core" or "parent" etc

Comment: Yes, it is only an example to evidentiate that there are three jars instead of two, but you are correct, a right name convention should be used. The best should also be to create different packages in different jars as I will edit in the answer